# FTP windows 2008r2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, ftp

Здравствуйте.Подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть проблема.Поставил filezilla server, добавил разрешение в фаерволлеНо могу только заходить через localhost, извне не могу заходить. Подскажите как избавиться от такой проблемы? Ставил родной IIS фтпэшник и была та же проблема (в принципе вариант с родным фтп тоже подойдет, но там система пользователей не нравится). Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

выключите фаерволл вприницпе и попробуйте, если проблема пройдет, значит чтото гдето не там  сделали... еще может быть в настройках сети гдето было, что комп НЕ виден по сети, оно скорее всего на все порты не отзывается.

Comment: Да ваш комментарий помог, еще надо было добавить правила в секурити групс на амазоне :) но т.к. я не упомянул об амазоне вы знать не могли.

Comment: @thunder а не подскажете почему может такое  быть: Сервер отправил пассивный ответ с неопределяемым адресом. Использую существующий адрес сервера (лог клиента файлзиллы)

Comment: Если кому пригодиться также надо добавить было Custom TCP Rule с портами x-y (и не забыть нажать Apply Changes(!))И добавить на filezilla этот же port ranges (x-y) в пассивном режиме